# Inheritance with Spring Java Config uses different bean

Tags: java, spring

The following example shows explicit wiring of dependencies using spring java config that results in a different bean being wired in while using and interface for a spring configuration class.

This seems like it shouldn't occur or at least give the normal warning that there are two beans as candidates for autowiring and it doesn't know which to select.

Any thoughts on this issue? My guess is there is no real name spacing between configuration classes as is implied by the syntax "this.iConfig.a()" Could this be considered a bug (if only for not warning about the 2 candidate beans)?

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main( final String[] args )
    {
        final ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext( IConfigImpl.class, ServiceConfig.class );
        final Test test = context.getBean( Test.class );

        System.out.println( test );
    }
}

public class Test
{
    private final String string;

    public Test( final String param )
    {
        this.string = param;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return this.string;
    }
}

@Configuration
public interface IConfig
{
    @Bean
    public String a();
}

@Configuration
public class IConfigImpl implements IConfig
{
    @Bean
    public String a()
    {
        return "GOOD String";
    }
}

@Configuration
public class ServiceConfig
{
    @Autowired
    IConfig iConfig;

    @Bean
    Test test()
    {
        return new Test( this.iConfig.a() );
    }

    @Bean
    String a()
    {
        return "BAD String";
    }
}
```

In this case, I would expect to have "GOOD String" to be always be wired in the Test object, but flipping the order of IConfigImpl.class, ServiceConfig.class in the context loader changes which string is loaded.

Tested with Spring 4.0.7

EDIT: Further testing shows this has nothing to to with inherented configs. Same thing results if you drop the IConfig interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Stepan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34424848/438154) has mentioned the issue of order. The following is about [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424635/inheritance-with-spring-java-config-uses-different-bean/34425748#comment56592570_34424848) on their answer

> Overriding beans of the same name makes sense, but in this case, I'm
>   specifically referencing the bean as specified in the `iConfig`
>   configuration. I would expect to get the one specified there.

In order to implement `@Configuration` and the caching of beans so that calls like

```
@Configuration
class Example {
    @Bean
    public UncaughtExceptionHandler uncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        return (thread, throwable) -> System.out.println(thread + " => " + throwable.getMessage());
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public Thread newThread() {
        Thread thread = new Thread();
        thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(uncaughtExceptionHandler()); // <<<<<< allowing this
        return thread;
    }
}
```

Spring actually uses CGLIB to create a proxy subtype of the `@Configuration` annotated class. This proxy maintains a reference to the backing `ApplicationContext` and uses that to resolve a bean.

So the call in your example

```
return new Test(this.iConfig.a());
```

isn't really invoking `IConfigImpl#a()`. It invokes [this code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/annotation/ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java#L307) (as of 4.2) from the proxy interceptor. The code uses the corresponding `Method` to determine the target bean name and uses the `ApplicationContext`'s `BeanFactory` to resolve the bean. Since the bean definition for a bean named `a` has already been overriden, that new bean definition gets used. That bean definition is using the `ServiceConfig#a()` method as its factory method.

This is described in the documentation, [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java-further-information-java-config)

> All `@Configuration` classes are subclassed at startup-time with CGLIB.
>   In the subclass, the child method checks the container first for any
>   cached (scoped) beans before it calls the parent method and creates a
>   new instance.

---

> Could this be considered a bug [...]?

I don't believe so. The behavior is documented.

Comment: Thanks, the internal implementation details clear it up. Still seems like a shame that I can't be 100% certain that `this.iConfig.a()` won't give me that bean, but i can see why it has to be that way.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this was a behavior of Spring for years.

If you redefine a bean, the one that is being loaded as last wins.

Another question would be how to control the order of bean loading when java configs are used. Check out this article http://www.java-allandsundry.com/2013/04/spring-beans-with-same-name-and.html which shows you how to do the ordering by using `@Import` of the other Spring java config.

> The solution is actually simple - if you need to override a previously
>   defined bean(without say the flexibility of autowiring with a
>   different bean name), either use the XML bean configuration for both
>   the bean being overridden and the overriding bean or use the
>   @Configuration. XML bean configuration is the first example in this
>   entry, the one with @Configuration would be something like this:

```
@Configuration
public class Context1JavaConfig {
    @Bean
    public MemberService memberService() {
        return new MemberSvcImpl1();
    }
}

@Configuration
@Import(Context1JavaConfig.class)
public class Context2JavaConfig {
    @Bean
    public MemberService memberService() {
        return new MemberSvcImpl2();
    }
}
```

Comment: Overriding beans of the same name makes sense, but in this case, I'm specifically referencing the bean as specified in the iConfig configuration. I would expect to get the one specified there.